# I'm trying to install my Entity Framework package using?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

```
PM> install-package entityframework
```

But I get the following message

> Install-Package : 'm' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 1, position 9397.
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + install-package <<<<  entityframework
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], XmlException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGet.VisualStudio.Cmdlets.InstallPackageCmdlet

Comment: restart visual studio.

Comment: try to install it via the NuGet package manager instead of the command line